# Combine values that start with the same value in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary looking something like this:

`a = {1: [['-','A'],['+','B'],['-','C']]}`

I want to reform it into the following:

`a = {1: [['-','AC'],['+','B']}`

or even better if I can get it to pandas data frame format:
`Col1    Col2    Col3`
`1       -       AC`
`1        +       B`

I've tried the following which seems like a way too complicated solution and also does not perfectly do what I want.

```
tmp = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key,value in a.items():
   for v in list(value):
      tmp[v[0]].append([v[1]])
```

which gives me a new dictionary:

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'-':['A','C'], '+':['B']}`

Edit: I have what I want now, but if anyone has a shorter smarter way to do it, I'd love to learn from you.

```
for key, value in a.items():
   tmp = collections.defaultdict(list)
   for v in value:
       tmp[v[0]].append(v[1])
    val = [[ i, ''.join(j)] for i,j in tmp.items()]
    a[key] = val
```

I also made sure that I always had both + and - values even if empty and turned it into dataframe using

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
```

Comment: What would you want if `a = {1: [['-','A'],['-','B'],['-','A']]}`?  Or `a = {1: [['-','A'],['+','B'],['-','C']],'x':[['*','Y'],['/','Z']]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A more pythonic approach would be this

The `set` function efficiently conveys that you only want the unique first elements of the pairs.

```
a = {1: [['-','A'],['+','B'],['-','C']]}
out = {}
for key, pairs in a.items():
   unique_firsts = set([pair[0] for pair in pairs])
   out[key]={
       unique_first: [pair[1] for pair in pairs if pair[0]==unique_first] for unique_first in unique_firsts
   }
print(out)
```

#### If you know in advance that you always want "-" and "+"

You can be even more pythonic:

```
a = {1: [["-", "A"], ["+", "B"], ["-", "C"]]}
firsts = ["-", "+"]
out = {
    key: [
        [first, 
            [pair[1] for pair in pairs if pair[0] == first]
        ] for first in firsts
    ]
    for key, pairs in a.items()
}
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have what I want now, but if anyone has a shorter smarter way to do it, I'd love to learn from you.

```
for key, value in a.items():
   tmp = collections.defaultdict(list)
   for v in value:
       tmp[v[0]].append(v[1])
    val = [[ i, ''.join(j)] for i,j in tmp.items()]
    a[key] = val
```

I also made sure that I always had both + and - values even if empty and turned it into dataframe using

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
```